# After Manager.SignInAsync - redirect to another page caused log out

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I've added a login requirement to all pages except `Index`.

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");
            options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Index");
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

You can come to my index page with a username in `Query` `....?UserName=Whatever`

I login the user by the username only.
After loggin successful, I redirect to another page, but the user name and password are required (although the login succeeded!).

The code at Index.cshtml:

```
@{
   var user = 
   Manager.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(UserName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   Manager.SignInAsync(user, true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   if (Manager.IsSignedIn(user))
   {
        Response.Redirect(anotherPage, true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Don’t do `.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` please. Properly await the result asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `app.UseAuthentication()` in startup Configure method:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc(); // Order here is important.
```

Comment: I did, of course.
The login is successful, and I get all user's information.
After redirect - the login is lost.
I try cancel the redirect, and navigate manually (write the url on browser) - it does not ask for a password.
How can I do it by Redirect?